# How to calculate remainder while accounting for hundredths digit for currency operations

Tags: c#, currency, modulus

I need to divide a USD amount by a number of months for a payment schedule, and I want to be able to get the remainder of the division if the money doesn't divide cleanly. Normally I would just use a modulus operation to get the remainder but I need to also account for the hundredths place, which modulus doesn't do. `$500.00` divvied up over 8 months is a perfectly valid amount at `$62.50` but a mod operation will return `$4.00`.

I'm currently using the `decimal` type for my currency operations, is there a better way to do what I'm doing or should I just go about and write a function that does this?

Comment: Show your calculations - yes `decimal` is the perfect type to use for monetary calculations.

Comment: ((value * 100) mod 8 ) / 100 ?

Comment: Add code to your question, not comments - and `value` is a `decimal`?

Comment: Also there's no `mod` operator in C#,  In C# it's `%`.  Please show your _exact_ C# code along with relevant declarations.

Comment: @IanMercer, I can't believe it was as simple as multiplying by a hundred before the mod operation and then dividing again by a hundred to get the true result. Your solution worked perfectly for me. If you'd like, please post this as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the remainder in cents by multiplying up, then applying mod and then dividing back down:

```
((value * 100) % 8 ) / 100
```